# Session aware spring bean

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Is there any way to define a spring bean which will be notified when data in session has changed?

I would also like to know pure java solution if possible. All I want is when i add/edit/delete data in httpsession then I want one java class to be notified to do some processing on that data.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Spring for this, the Servlet API provides that out-of-the-box, via the [`HttpSessionAttributeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) interface:

> This listener interface can be implemented in order to get notifications of changes to the attribute lists of sessions within this web application.

You declare it as a `<listener>` in your `web.xml` file.  See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionattributelistener-example/) for an example.

In don't know of a specific Spring-friendly way of doing this, though, I think you'll have to use the above listener approach, and notify your Spring beans from there.